# How to debug geth with delve?

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging

When I run delve as below, it errors about internal packages. How to overcome it?

```
$ dlv debug cmd/geth/main.go
cmd/geth/main.go:35:2: use of internal package not allowed
exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who meet the same question.

Delve need extra param `-gcflags=all='-N -l'` in the build cmd, you can build it manual instead of by running `make geth`:

```
go build -o ./build/bin/geth   -gcflags=all='-N -l' -v ./cmd/geth
```

Then you can run

```
dlv  --headless --listen=:2345 --api-version=2 exec ./build/bin/geth -- ${yourGethParams}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since go-ethereum migrated to go.mod, I have been able to do this by

```
cd go-ethereum
dlv debug --headless --listen=:2345 --log --api-version=2 github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth -- $GETH_OPTS
```

I do have the following CGO env vars set. (This may not be necessary though)

```
CGO_LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
CGO_CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

I happen to use headless & listen along with attaching to fit in with a docker compose workflow. exec should work just as well